# How do I zip two arrays into one array of strings containing the values

Tags: javascript, arrays

For instance, if I have two arrays that look like this:

```
var array1 = ['a','b'];
var array2 = [1, 1];
```

The output array should be:

```
var newArray = ['a:1', 'b:1']
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `map` like this:

```js
var array1 = ['a','b'], array2 = [1, 1];
var newArray = array1.map((e, i) => `${e}:${array2[i]}`);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map the value of the iterating array and from the other array the value of the actual index.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b'],
    array2 = [1, 1],
    result = array1.map((a, i) => [a, array2[i]].join(':'));

console.log(result);
```

The same with an arbitrary count of arrays

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b'],
    array2 = [1, 1],
    result = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + ':' + b[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use lodash you can do this very easily with [`zipWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipWith). It takes arrays and combines the values grouped by index according to a function you provide:

```
var newArr = lodash.zipWith(array1, array2, (arr1val, arr2val) => `${arr1val}:${arr2val}`);
```